# Bulk insert not processing void files

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I am trying to load data using Bulk Insert in sql server using -

```
BULK INSERT CUSTOMERE FROM  'F:\\TEMPP\\Invoice_1500645000008_24072017_1127.csv' WITH (FORMATFILE = 'F:\\TEMPP\\Invoice.fmt')
```

But in this file i have Header only (Means 0 record) then its throwing below given error :
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 86
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 86
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 86
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

whenever i am loading with data its loading...

can we process 0 record file without Error.??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could put BULK INSERT in TRY..CATCH however you have to run it as dynamic query otherwise TRY..CATCH is not going to catch error. This gives you option to log information about empty file as well.

```
BEGIN TRY
 DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)
 SET @cmd = 'BULK INSERT CUSTOMERE FROM ''F:\TEMPP\Invoice_1500645000008_24072017_1127.csv'' WITH (FORMATFILE = ''F:\TEMPP\Invoice.fmt'')
 EXECUTE (@cmd)
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 BULK INSERT CUSTOMERE 
     FROM 'F:\TEMPP\Invoice_1500645000008_24072017_1127.csv'
     WITH 
     (
        FORMATFILE = 'F:\TEMPP\Invoice.fmt'
     );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: also you must have bulk permission for linked servers

Comment: goto sql server mng studio and object explorer_server object_linked server_ and then get properties

Comment: @Toby Speight  I EDITED

Comment: I still don't see any explanation.